# Return my email-address Vb.net / outlook 2010 application

Tags: vb.net, outlook

I'm building a VB.net application.
I want to check the email address from outlook for the authentication.

I started with the followings code :

```
Dim objOL as Outlook.Application 
Set objOL = New Outlook.Application
```

what should I do to return my email address ( Knowing that I'm opening outlook during the excution).

Thanks in advance

Comment: This seems like a bad idea.

Comment: why? my idea is to have this application connected with sql server database where the the allowed email addresses for authentification.
and to make this quick I would like only to check the email address from the outlook application.

Comment: But an email address alone is insufficient for authentication. Anyone could configure their outlook client to spoof someone else's email address. What about the password? Dear $deity, I hope this isn't for a corporate application.

Comment: thanks for your answer.I Would like two have to way to connect to the application. 1) Email from outlook checking ( to make this thing quick ) 2) or the traditional method ID/password. the first one would be for me easier for the users . my app is not connected with internet the first way will be secure ?what do you think?

Comment: I cannot be more clear. **Simply using the email address is insufficient for authentication and *extremely insecure*.** In fact, it sounds like you're planning on doing everything locally, and manipulating the database from your app? Does this DB not have authentication enabled itself?

Comment: Ok thanks a lot Jonathon . but I think in my case the risk is not very big. because my application is connected with a database in the commun server. the user should be first connected to the server to be able to connect with the app ( even if he changes his email, he can't use the app because the connection between the app and Db is broken)

Comment: Yes I'm planning on doing everything locally

Comment: How does your app authenticate with the DB? Is there any authentication?

Comment: my DB has a password. it will be located in the commun server which is not accessible by all

Comment: But now you're putting that password directly in this application. Anyone who has this app can modify the entire database.  Please, talk to someone who knows what they're doing about the security of this application. It sounds like you're setting yourself up for disaster.

Comment: this application is made to let the users add and delete things from the database. Even if some one has the code , he can't access to the database , because its located in a local server. and if he has the access to the server he can reach the folder where the database exists and delete it.

Comment: But the application *can* access the database. It has the credentials hard-coded inside. And any idiot can open it up in a hex editor and get the database credentials.

Comment: the app can't access the database . the user should be connected to the server first . because I'm giving the app a link like this E:\.... If the user is not connected to the server the app won't find the database ( cos E:\... is not found )

Comment: So it is a file-based database. I give up.

Comment: Yes it is file-based dababase. its secure then ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This one worked for me :

```
objOL.Session.CurrentUser.AddressEntry.GetExchangeUser().PrimarySmtpAddress
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the following might do what you want:

```
Dim objOL as Outlook.Application 
Set objOL = New Outlook.Application

Dim email As String = objOL.Session.CurrentUser.AddressEntry.Address
```

See: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff184601.aspx for more info

Comment: Thanks a lot @Matt Wilko

Comment: You can also upvote this if you found it useful, which it sounds like you did

Comment: I wish i could but I m new here , I m not allowed to do it. I have to reach some number of point before I have the right to do it . but when I got the right to do it I'll do it

Comment: Hi Matt I tought that the problem is solved but this function  dosen't return the email address